# Trouble with XQuery SQL statement to get correct parent/child value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

XML Schema: (Assumes that the XMLNAMESPACES are already set AS a and b)

```
<Layer1 xmlns="a">
  <Layer2 xmlns="b">
    <Layer3>
      <id>val1</id>
      <data>False</data>
    </Layer3>
    <Layer3>
      <id>val2</id>
      <data>True</data>
    </Layer3>
  </Layer2>
</Layer1>
```

I am using this bit of sql to attempt to accomplinsh my task.

```
ITEM.value('(/a:Layer1/b:Layer2/b:Layer3)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS ReturnValue
```

What I am trying to do is get only the true values where id='val2' AND data='True'. Something like this:

```
ITEM.value('(/a:Layer1/b:Layer2/b:Layer3[id="val2" and data="True"]/b:data)[0]', 'varchar(max)') AS ReturnValue
```

For some reason the above returns null. I'd assume it is a syntax error.

In this query I would like the value to be returned as True from any Layer3 Parent where the id and data are following the conditions. I'd appreciate any help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I take, that this is SQL-Server...

Your XML defines a **default namespace** for the first node `<Layer1>` and **again a default namespace** for the `<Layer2>`.

That means, that **all elements below `<Layer2>`** are in this new default namespace.

Your code misses the namespaces here `[id="val2" and data="True"]`, but I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve actually...

```
DECLARE @ITEM XML=
N'<Layer1 xmlns="a">
  <Layer2 xmlns="b">
    <Layer3>
      <id>val1</id>
      <data>False</data>
    </Layer3>
    <Layer3>
      <id>val2</id>
      <data>True</data>
    </Layer3>
  </Layer2>
</Layer1>';
```

--This query will find the value "True" within `<data>` below a `<Layer3>`, where the `<id>` is "val2":

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('a' AS a,'b' AS b)
SELECT @ITEM.value('(/a:Layer1/b:Layer2/b:Layer3[b:id="val2"]/b:data/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)');
```

You might use a `*:` in front of each and any name to use a namespace wildcard:

```
SELECT @ITEM.value('(/*:Layer1/*:Layer2/*:Layer3[*:id="val2"]/*:data/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)');
```

One more approach was to define your *inner default ns* like this, which saves some typing:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('a' AS a, DEFAULT 'b')
SELECT @ITEM.value('(/a:Layer1/Layer2/Layer3[id="val2"]/data/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)');
```